# SwiftUI horizontal ScrollView has invisible padding

Tags: swift, scrollview, swiftui, padding

Nested horizontal ScrollView has invisible padding from the top. I've tried to add ".padding(.top, 0)" for the ScrollView and for the content, but it doesn't work. Is it a bug or it is possible to remove this padding?

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Text one")
      Text("Text two")
      ScrollView(.horisontal, showsIndicators: false) {
      Text("Text with strange top padding")
    }
}.padding(.horizontal)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what is `ScrollingView` but with standard `ScrollView` provided example works well (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

Here is a demo with added border around scroll view for better visibility

```
struct TestHorizontalScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
              Text("Text one")
              Text("Text two")
              ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                Text("Text with strange top padding")
            }.border(Color.red)
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Do you see the gap between the "Text two" and the text inside the ScrollView? This is what I talked about.

Comment: @yoprst, ah that one.. then you need just specify explicit `spacing` in VStack, because if none then system selects default between each pair of sibling views (and no padding hardcoding as you accepted).

Comment: True, vertical view has weird padding as well. How did you solved it in the end?